# How can I create a disabled trigger in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers, ddl

When using Oracle you can create a disabled trigger specifing the word DISABLE before the trigger body. How can I achive the same effect in Sql Server?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you really must create the trigger disabled then create and disable it within a transaction:

```
begin tran
go
create trigger t_i on t after insert as begin /* trigger body */ end
go
disable trigger t_i on t
commit
go
```

The GOs are there because CREATE TRIGGER must be the first statement in a batch, but depending on how you deploy your code you can probably make it look a bit neater.

Answer (score 2):

The way I did it was to EXEC both the create and the disable like:

```
EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER trigger_on_myTable ON myTable <Trigger body> ');

EXEC('DISABLE TRIGGER trigger_on_myTable ON myTable');
```

This allowed me to create and disable in the same script without the any GO's.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a solution that doesn't require a transaction, but that also eliminates the chance of the trigger firing and doing its thing between the moment it is created and the moment it is disabled, then you can create the trigger with basically no code in it, then disable it, and then alter it to include its actual body:

```
create trigger dbo.MyTrigger
    on dbo.MyTable
    after insert

as

declare @Foo int;

--Trigger body must have at least a statement (or an "external name") so that's why the above dummy declare.

go

disable trigger dbo.MyTrigger
    on dbo.MyTable;

go

alter trigger dbo.MyTrigger
    on dbo.MyTable
    after insert

as

declare @Foo int;

--Remove above declare statement and insert actual trigger code here.

go
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to really work, since altering the trigger will enable it immediately. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/159022

Comment: No, it does not. (I just did a test.)

Answer (score 0):

1st create empty trigger (performing no action),
2nd disable it,
3rd alter it with the desired content,
4th enable it when needed

Answer (score -1):

In management studio Expand Trigger folder under table and Right Click on Trigger and Disable.

```
DISABLE TRIGGER { [ schema_name . ] trigger_name [ ,...n ] | ALL }
ON { object_name | DATABASE | ALL SERVER } [ ; ]
```

[MSDN:DISABLE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748)

```
ENABLE TRIGGER { [ schema_name . ] trigger_name [ ,...n ] | ALL }
ON { object_name | DATABASE | ALL SERVER } [ ; ]
```

[MSDN:ENABLE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182706)

[sql-server-disable-all-triggers-on-a-database-disable-all-triggers-on-all-servers](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/29/sql-server-disable-all-triggers-on-a-database-disable-all-triggers-on-all-servers/)

Comment: No, i want a disabled trigger at the momment of creation.

Answer (score -1):

T-SQL provides a DISABLE TRIGGER statement that accomplishes the same thing. You can find the details here: [DISABLE TRIGGER SYNTAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: No, i want a disabled trigger at the momment of creation.